# Is there a guide to the different bootstrap classes for ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I have been looking for several days for some explanation on the different classes that can be used when creating views in bootstrap. The only thing I can find is how to install bootstrap, which isn't helpful.

```
    <div class="row mb-auto">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="row no-gutters border mb-4">
                <div class="col p-4">
                    <p class="card-text">
                        <div class="form-inline">
```

I'm trying to create a form, and I know about taghelpers. I am not asking about taghelpers but rather the different classes that can be used in a div wrap. Is there some sort of guide where I can see visually what each class creates in a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation is very helpful in explaining all the classes:

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/
- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/
- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/typography/

`mb-4` is explained [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/). `mb` stands for margin bottom. `-4` means that the you want the margin to be of size 4. Sizes are defined from 0 through 5 and are ordered in ascending order.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!